# .net Core appsettings - Multiple Environments on same IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

On a single server (in IIS), how can I use a different configuration (appsettings.x.json files) per site/application?

This is so I can use the same CI build artifacts for both deployments.

I understand how the appsettings.environment is picked up by the Server System Environment variable (ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT), and that works for a couple of our environments.  However we have **one server with more than one environment** hosted on it.  ie. CI  *and* UAT on the same server + IIS.

Comment: How are you defining the environments on the deployment server?

Comment: On the server in System Environment variables:  ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

Comment: How are you deploying? We use Octopus and have used a few approaches.  Having an Environment.json file that the deployment modifies to set the environment. This is then loaded as the first thing to get the environment, so the appsettings.*.sjon approach can be used. Lately we are moving more to storing configuration in octopus itself, and letting it handle creation of config files. I'm not sure what I like best.

Comment: @Christian Sparre We are using VSTS to build and deploy.  
I'm considering adding the <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="XYZ" /> in the web.config file, during the release step. As I believe that overrides the system setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem and ended up specifying the environment variable inside of the web.config.

```
<aspNetCore /* omitting other aspNetCore arguments for brevity */>
    <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Staging" />
    </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

Comment: That's what I have alluded to in my comments above. So transform that setting as it's deployed?

Comment: If you are using IIS in front of your ASP.NET Core process it seems like a great way to go.

Comment: It's what I would say is probably the most straight forward option in your situation.